# ASP.NET MVC Cast viewmodel into generic interface type in action filter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, generics, viewmodel, action-filter

I have the following classes in my ASP.NET MVC5 application:

```
public abstract class BaseItem
{ }

public class DerivedItem1 : BaseItem
{ }

public class DerivedItem2 : BaseItem
{ }

public interface IItemViewModel<T>
    where T : BaseItem
{
    T Item { get; set; }
}

public class ItemViewModel<T> : IItemViewModel<T>
    where T : BaseItem
{
    public T Item { get; set; }
}
```

My controllers look like these:

```
[AutoAssignItem]
public class DerivedItem1Controller : ItemControllerBase<DerivedItem1>
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new ItemViewModel<DerivedItem1>();

        // I'd like to avoid setting the Item property here
        // and instead delegate that task to my filter
        // itemService.GetCurrentItems returns an instance
        // of type DerivedItem1.
        // model.Item = itemService.GetCurrentItem();

        return View(model);
    }
}

[AutoAssignItem]
public class DerivedItem2Controller : ItemControllerBase<DerivedItem2>
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new ItemViewModel<DerivedItem2>();

        // I'd like to avoid setting the Item property here
        // and instead delegate that task to my filter
        // itemService.GetCurrentItems returns an instance
        // of type DerivedItem2.
        // model.Item = itemService.GetCurrentItem();

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

I have an AutoAssignItem action filter where I'd like to set the Item property on my view model which could be of type ItemViewModel<DerivedItem1> or ItemViewModel<DerivedItem2>:

```
public class AutoAssignItem : ActionFilterAttribute, IActionFilter
{
    public void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var viewModel = filterContext.Controller.ViewData.Model;

        // The viewModel type here could either be
        // ItemViewModel<DerivedItem1> or ItemViewModel<DerivedItem2>
        // So I try passing in BaseItem as the type parameter and cast
        var model = viewModel as IItemViewModel<BaseItem>;

        // But model is always null :(
        if (model == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        // Here I can also try and get the implemented interface type
        // var interfaceType = viewModel.GetType().GetInterfaces().Where(i => i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IItemViewModel<>)).SingleOrDefault();
        // And try converting it but this would require the viewModel
        // to implement the IConvertible interface which I want to avoid
        // var model = Convert.ChangeType(viewModel, interfaceType);

        // If model is not null, then set the Item property
        // through a service based on contextual information
        // Here itemService.GetCurrentItem() would return an Item
        // with the correct type such as DerivedItem1 if the action
        // on the DerivedItem1Controller had run
        model.Item = itemService.GetCurrentItem();
    }
}
```

Note that BaseItem will have several derived classes, not just two as in the example above. My question is how do I cast viewmodel such that I can access and set the Item property?

If I make T in IItemViewModel<T> to be covariant, then I'm not able to set the Item property in the action filter as it'll be getter-only.

As an aside, I'm trying to replicate the generic controller and viewmodel structure as normally is implemented when using the Episerver CMS API. The difference being, in the CMS, it's all about pages. So the controller would look like:

```
public class HomePageController : PageControllerBase<HomePage>
{
    public ActionResult Index(HomePage currentPage)
    {
        var model = new PageViewModel<HomePage>();
        model.CurrentPage = currentPage;

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve? I'm just curious.

Comment: Win - I've added comments to clarify my intent.

Comment: If you were just trying to *get* `model.Item` in the filter I'd suggest separating the getter into a covariant interface but the concept of variance exists exactly to protect against the logically invalid thing you're trying to do - assign a `BaseItem` (presumably the return type of `GetCurrentItem`) to a variable of type `T : BaseItem`. It's hard to know exactly what you're trying to achieve here but it sounds like you're looking for a workaround when what you need is a different approach altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround, I've decided to set the view model's Item property by overriding the `OnResultExecuting` method of the base controller rather than in an action filter. That way, I'll be able to access the type parameter of the view model and cast accordingly :)

```
public abstract ItemControllerBase<T> : Controller
    where T : BaseItem
{
    protected override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);

        var viewModel = filterContext.Controller.ViewData.Model;

        var model = viewModel as IItemViewModel<T>;
        if (model == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        model.Item = itemService.GetCurrentItem();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are trying to make an action filter which will apply the same Item-setting rule to multiple actions so that you don't have to repeat the same Item-setting logic in each action.

I used all the code that you provided in a new MVC 5 project and made the following changes, just so I could see what was going on in the page created by my action called "Test."

```
public abstract class BaseItem
{
    public String Type { get; set; }
    public String Note { get; set; }

    public abstract void Alter();
}

public class DerivedItem1 : BaseItem
{
    public DerivedItem1()
    {
        Type = "DerivedItem1";
    }

    public override void Alter()
    {
        Note = "Altered by the code specific to DerivedItem1";
    }
}

public class DerivedItem2 : BaseItem
{
    public DerivedItem2()
    {
        Type = "DerivedItem2";
    }

    public override void Alter()
    {
        Note = "Altered by the code specific to DerivedItem2";
    }
}

public class MyActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute, IActionFilter
{
    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var viewModel = filterContext.Controller.ViewData.Model;

        var model = viewModel as IItemViewModel<BaseItem>;
        // model is always null :(
        if (model == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        model.Item = new DerivedItem2(); // Set the Item property here;
    }
}
```

And in the Home controller, I created the following Test action:

```
[MyActionFilter]
public ActionResult Test()
{
    var vm = new ItemViewModel<BaseItem>();
    vm.Item = new DerivedItem1();
    return View(vm);
}
```

And then in the view for the Test action:

```
@model ActionFilterTest.ViewModels.ItemViewModel<ActionFilterTest.Models.BaseItem>

<h4>BaseItem</h4>
<hr />
<label for="item">Model.Item.Type: </label>
<div name="item">@Model.Item.Type</div>

@{ Model.Item.Alter(); }

<label for="note">Model.Item.Note:</label>"
<div name="note">@Model.Item.Note</div>
```

And when I browse to Home/Test, it displays that `Model.Item.Type` is `DerivedItem2`, not `DerivedItem1`, and that `Note` was assigned by the overridden method in the correct, derived class, even though `Alter()` was called on an object that was declared to be of type `ItemViewModel<BaseItem>`, which is what I expected. Is that not what you want?

**Update**:
I have a feeling that you are not going to consider the suggestion below to be a very flexible solution, since you need to make an `if` branch for each derived type. You may be able to fashion some sort of dynamic cast through reflection. I don't really want to go there. There seems to be consensus in the posts that I have read, that dynamic casting is somewhat pointless and even ill-advised, since it is attempting to circumvent a compile-time type checking mechanism that is meant to prevent runtime errors and maintain integrity. The following changes take the new details that you provided in your latest comment into account, and work correctly in my project.

```
public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    var viewModel = filterContext.Controller.ViewData.Model;

    var model = viewModel as IItemViewModel<BaseItem>;

    if (viewModel.GetType() == typeof(ItemViewModel<DerivedItem1>))
    {
        ((ItemViewModel<DerivedItem1>)viewModel).Item = new DerivedItem1();
    }
    else if (viewModel.GetType() == typeof(ItemViewModel<DerivedItem2>))
    {
        ((ItemViewModel<DerivedItem2>)viewModel).Item = new DerivedItem2();
    }
    else
    {
        throw new InvalidCastException("Unsupported cast from type: " + viewModel.GetType().FullName);
    }
}
```

Then I deleted the `Test` action from `HomeController` and added the following:

```
[MyActionFilter]
public ActionResult Test1()
{
    var vm = new ItemViewModel<DerivedItem1>();
    return View(vm);
}

[MyActionFilter]
public ActionResult Test2()
{
    var vm = new ItemViewModel<DerivedItem2>();
    return View(vm);
}
```

With the following views:

```
@model ActionFilterTest.ViewModels.ItemViewModel<ActionFilterTest.Models.DerivedItem1>

<label for="type">Model.Item.Type:</label>
<div name="type">@Model.Item.Type</div>

@{ Model.Item.Alter(); }

<label for="note">Model.Item.Note:</label>"
<div name="note">@Model.Item.Note</div>
```

and:

```
@model ActionFilterTest.ViewModels.ItemViewModel<ActionFilterTest.Models.DerivedItem2>

<label for="type">Model.Item.Type:</label>
<div name="type">@Model.Item.Type</div>

@{ Model.Item.Alter(); }

<label for="note">Model.Item.Note:</label>"
<div name="note">@Model.Item.Note</div>
```

Comment: Kent Weigel - Well, not quite. You are right in that I want to apply the action filter to avoid repetition of setting the Item property on the view model. However, the type parameter for the viewmodel will always be set to a derived class (and **not** BaseItem) in my controller action, for ex: `var vm = new ItemViewModel<DerivedItem1>();` I've updated my question with more comments.

Comment: I edited my answer to show that polymorphism works as intended. When you assign an instance of a more derived class to a variable declared as a less derived class, when you call the variable's methods, the actual method called will be that of the derived type. You will have to explain to me why this won't work for you. If you had declared the variable of a more derived type and tried to assign it a value of another equally derived type, such as `ItemViewModel<DerivedItem1>` and `ItemViewModel<DerivedItem2>`, respectively, I don't think you would have much luck.

Comment: And since you can't instantiate an abstract class, you're automatically protected from accidentally doing so, and the intention to assign `vm`, or in your case `model`, only derived types is implied.

Comment: Your code works because you've instantiated the view model by passing in BaseItem as the type parameter `var vm = new ItemViewModel<BaseItem>();` in the controller action. I cannot do this as my requirement is that I need to pass only derived class types for ex: `var vm = new ItemViewModel<DerivedItem1>();` in the controller action and then set the view model's Item property which will be of type DerivedItem1 in the action filter.

Comment: The view model in one controller action would be `var vm = new ItemViewModel<DerivedItem1>()` while another action method could have `var vm = new ItemViewModel<DerivedItem2>()` instead. The issue I have is how to cast the view model to the correct type (either ItemViewModel<DerivedItem1> or ItemViewModel<DerivedItem2>) in my action filter as I wouldn't know the type at compile time.

Comment: Thanks Kent. As you mentioned already, this solution wouldn't scale up as I'll have several derived item classes.